# What's the difference between "происходить", "случаться" and "оказаться"?

Tags: разница

What's the difference between "происходить", "случаться" and "оказаться"?

Examples very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"**Происходить**" = to take place, to occur, to happen. ''На Калке произошла битва между русскими и монголами'' = At the Kalka River, a battle took place between the Russians and the Mongols.'' ''За время Вашего отсутствия многое произошло'' = ''Many things happened during your absence.'' Note that the word has an additional, very different meaning: to stem, to originate. ''Род Ивановых происходит от богатого купца'' = ''The Ivanov dynasty originated from a rich merchant.''

"**Случаться**" = similar to ''происходить'', but has a flavour of accidental or unexpected character of what happened. ''Случилось несчастье'' = ''A misfortune (accidentally) occurred.'' ''Да, такое случалось'' = ''Yes, such things used to (accidentally) happen.''

"**Оказаться**" = to turn out to be, to prove to be, to find oneself in a certain condition or at a certain place. ''Он оказался таким глупым!'' = ''He proved to be so stupid.'' ''У нее с собой не оказалось билета'' = ''She turned out not to have a ticket.'' ''Я оказался на третьем этаже'' = ''I found myself to be on the 3rd level''.